# passing value of check box using ajax with name attribute as key and not id as key

Tags: ajax, checkbox, controller

i want to know how can we pass check box value using ajax as by using name attribute but not id attribute for example

```
<input type="checkbox"   id="s1" value="1" checked>S1&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox"  id="s2" value="2" checked>S2<br>
            <input type="checkbox"  id="s3" value="3" checked>S3&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox"  id="s4" value="4" checked>S4</td>
```

if i pass this checkbox value using id as attribute like below,

```
.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getData',
            data: {
              fromDate: $('#fromDate').val(),
              toDate: $('#toDate').val(),
              location: $('#location').val(),
              section: $('#section').val(),
              s1: $('#s1').is(":checked"),
              s2: $('#s2').is(":checked"),
              s3: $('#s3').is(":checked"),
              s4: $('#s4').is(":checked"),
        },
```

then in controller i am getting these values using seperate request.getparameters("key");

but what i want to give checkbox like below

```
input type="checkbox"   name="s" value="1" checked>S1&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox"  name="s" value="2" checked>S2<br>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="s" value="3" checked>S3&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox"  name="s" value="4" checked>S4</td>
```

from this using ajax i want to do like below as

```
.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getData',
        data: {
          fromDate: $('#fromDate').val(),
          toDate: $('#toDate').val(),
          location: $('#location').val(),
          section: $('#section').val(),
          s: $('#s').val()
    },
```

and in controller i want to get it using request.getParameterValues("s"); and this will return string[].

can u plz help me to get this , actually i was getting this in normal Action/submit in servlet but in ajax i am getting null values only..

Answer (score 0):

try something like `s: $('input[name="s"]:checked').val()`

Comment: yes what ever you are suggesting give always the size as one , and i tried like th e below and it worked thank u  --->>>  var s = [];
      $("input:checkbox[name=s]:checked").each(function() {
         s.push($(this).val());
    });